# How to recover data from a corrupted /base/ directory?

Tags: restore, recovery, postgresql-9.5

I have deleted all directory by mistake except from the given link
`/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/base/18686` and so on.

I have 4 such directories, now I want to get data back from those folder as they are very important.

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Can you please help us?

Comment: When you state: “_I have deleted all dirwctories..._” what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Restore from your backups.

Comment: You can possibly try to recover the files using some disk recovery tool.  I wouldn't expect this to work without issues, and when there are, you are totally out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have deleted folders like

```
pg_xlog
pg_tblspc
pg_serial
```

With only **base directory** :   /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main/base/18686
You can't recover data.
You can refer to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/storage-file-layout.html).

If you have a dump file recovering from it might be the only solution.

Comment: Yes it has been deleted and you understand correctly now can I ask one for the thing here I have 30th June 2017 database backup and if I restore that database and I will have all other directories which you are asking is it possible I can copy the data of this directory which only is there into the old backup and thereby I can recover the backup all the data

Comment: You can't just copy parts from one backup and merge it with another, if that's what you mean. If you have lost valuable data which may still exist in some of the files, I suggest you get in touch with a Postgresql consulting company with expertise in data recovery. Only you can decide if that's worth what it will cost you.

Comment: Thanks I will contact then after trying couple of thing.

Comment: The files in directory of 30th june 2017 database will be different and cannot merge with your base/ directory

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on the google shows that probably no low-level postgresql table recovery tool exists.

So you have to implement your own one.

Last time I've checked it, postgresql has the "classical" SQL low-level table layout format:

- Table files are ordered in blocks (8192 byte)
- Every block is from a block header and a set of rows, *starting anywhere inside the block*
- And the rows contain your low-level hexa data.

If you remember your table format, it is not very hard to implement a tool, typically in C, to create at least a partial recover, but it would be probably some days of work to have an usable result.

Have always backups.

Comment: You are absolutely right but what you are suggesting he is out of my cup of tea so any other solution available please suggest

Comment: @user3752051 You would require a recovery tool which wasn't implemented until now. If you have luck, others will have better ideas.